# I created a `const` inside `this.api.getApi().subscribe(({tool,beuty})`, how can I run it inside my `if` statement?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a `const`  inside `this.api.getApi().subscribe(({tool,beuty})`, how can I run it inside my `if` statement like this:

```
if (evt.index === 0) {aa}
```

I will create more lines like this and I want to run them with different `if` statements:

```
this.beu=beuty.slice(0,this.i+=15);
```

Is there a better solution to do that?

Code:

```
  onScrollDown(evt:any ) {     
    setTimeout(()=>{      
        this.api.getApi().subscribe(({tool,beuty}) => {       
            const aa=this.beu=beuty.slice(0,this.i+=15);
        })
    if (evt.index === 0) {aa}       
    },1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a variable declared using `const` outside its block scope. Try the following and you will get an `ReferenceError`:

```js
function foo() {
    const bar = "bar";
}
console.log(bar);
```

So, you can't use `aa` outside of the callback passed to `this.api.getApi().subscribe()`.

If you want to be able to use `aa` outside of the callback you can define `aa` using `let`. In code:

```js
  onScrollDown(evt:any) {
      
    setTimeout(() => {

        // Add this:
        let aa;
         
        this.api.getApi().subscribe(({tool,beuty}) => {
            // Change this:
            aa=this.beu=beuty.slice(0,this.i+=15);
        })
     
        if (evt.index === 0) {aa}
            
    }, 1000);
   

  }
```

I hope this helps. I can't really tell if it works because I don't have the whole script.